# What is the best way to interact with the values of a dictionary list and save as string?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate through the following list of dictionaries to produce output:

```
authors = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Grace Hopper'}, 
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Karl Marx'}
]
```

expected output:

```
'Grace Hopper, Karl Marx'
```

My code is missing something:

```
for item in authors:
    for author in item.values():
        print(author)
```

Output:

```
1
Grace Hopper
2
Karl Marx
```

How to solve it using a simple`for` loop? How to do it using list compression?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `str.join`:

```
d = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Grace Hopper'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Karl Marx'}]
new_d = ', '.join([i['name'] for i in d])
```

Output:

```
'Grace Hopper, Karl Marx'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
from operator import itemgetter

authors = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Grace Hopper'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Karl Marx'}
]

print(', '.join(map(itemgetter('name'), authors)))  # -> Grace Hopper, Karl Marx
```